# Return Path no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, funções

Eu configurei na unha a função wp-mail do wordpress responsável pelo envio de emails no site através do formulário. Se o wordpress atualizar eu tenho que que fazer essa adição  de códigos novamente na função?

Comment: "eu configurei na unha" o que exatamente vc fez? alterou o `wp-includes/pluggable.php`?

Comment: Isso mesmo, adicionei essa classe:
`class email_return_path {
   function __construct() {
  add_action( 'phpmailer_init', array( $this, 'fix' ) );    
   }
 
 function fix( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->Sender = $phpmailer->From;
 }
}
 
new email_return_path();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Se o wordpress atualizar eu tenho que que fazer essa adição de códigos novamente na função?

Se o WordPress atualizar **as suas edições serão perdidas**, não é uma boa prática alterar os arquivos do `core` (nada que esteja fora da pasta `wp-content`).

**Como resolver?**

A função [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) é do tipo [`pluggable`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions), como o nome do arquivo diz. Isso quer dizer que ela só é executada no original se uma outra função não for especificada com o mesmo nome.

```
// wp-includes/pluggable.php` linha 142 no WP 4.7
if ( !function_exists( 'wp_mail' ) ) :
    function wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers = '', $attachments = array() )
```

Portanto basta criar uma nova função chamada `wp_mail()` em um `plugin` ou `mu-plugin`, com o seu código personalizado - que pode ser uma cópia´do original com a sua alteração -, e a sua versão será usada no lugar da original.

Comment: muito obrigado, foi muito claro. Estou já aqui criando um plugin para isso e quero instala-lo em todas as minhas aplicações que usa wordpress para não ter dor de cabeça depois.